# Symfony not installated on window xp with Xamp: give apache error

Tags: apache, symfony1, symfony-1.4, wamp

I tried to install symfony1.4 on window-XP with xamp

i install symfony and create project. Helloword

When i open project in localhost. It give apache error.

I checked apache error log two error come:

First:It access permissions error.
Second:Client denied by server configuration.

Thanks In advance
project C:\xamp\htdocs\helloword\

also give CLI error when i create module under app

Comment: Can we have a look at your apache config ?

Comment: @IT Engg Can you post your virtual host config?

Comment: @Denys<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:81>
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\helloword\web"
DirectoryIndex index.php
<Directory "C:\wamp\www\helloword\web">
AllowOverride All
Allow from All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 1):

Hm, maybe try this:

instead of

```
 <Directory "C:\wamp\www\helloword\web">
        AllowOverride All 
        All Allow from All 
  </Directory>
```

this:

```
 <Directory "C:\wamp\www\helloword\web">
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks +Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

and restart apache.